# Installing PyQt4 on Mac OSx Mavericks?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, installation, pyqt, pyqt4

http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

I tried many solutions on internet including

```
brew install qt
brew install sip
brew install pyqt
```

to successfully install it on osx. 
I am using PyCharm IDE to python development and want to install it for python 3.

I just cannot download pyqt4 libraries to mac,
is there some specific steps i need to follow?
Easy way? Hard way? anything...

Sorry, I am new to mac world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I've found is to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). Once installed, simply run

```
sudo port install py34-pyqt4
```

and it will do the rest - install Python 3.4, pyqt4, and all the dependencies. You'll need to configure PyCharm to use the MacPorts version of Python (found in `/opt/local/bin`), but after that you should be all set. There are many modules available through MacPorts, and for those that aren't you can always install `py34-pip`.

Comment: I did it but when i try to import it it says:

  `from PyQt4.QtCore import  *
  ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4'`

Comment: @Python are you sure you set up PyCharm correctly? The Python executable should be `/opt/local/bin/python3` (assuming you installed in the default location), and `site-packages` should be in `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages` (I'm going from memory here, you'll have to verify the actual path). Check in the `site-packages` folder for a `PyQt4` folder. Also, run `/opt/local/bin/python3` from the command line and try to import PyQt4 that way, just to verify that the installation worked.

Comment: I edited Interpreter location to /opt/local/bin/python3.4 and it worked... but as soon as I opened new project... with same interpreter it gave same error 'no module found' dont know why.. although THANKSSSSS for ur help it worked finally to some extend......

Comment: @Python glad I could help. Good luck figuring out PyCharm! I'm a Sublime Text user myself, and while it lacks some of the features of a full-fledged IDE, I've customized it with several plugins for Python coding, and I really like it.

Answer (score 19):

You can install it with homebrew using the `--with-python3` flag:

```
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```

And relink the site packages if necessary.

Comment: `brew uninstall sip` and `brew install sip --with-python3` solved the problem.

Comment: maybe this needs an update, given that `--with-python3` is not a valid option anymore...

Answer (score 3):

I know this is from a year ago but this may help someone...

**Note:** This is for [PyQT5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and Python 3. It is an alternative to using homebrew.

### Background

If you installed Python 3.x, it installs in a separate directory (leaving your Mac version alone). After adding the new `directories` to your path, most people can just use `python3.5` (or whatever version) to access it without having to change over `python` alias.

Also note that Python comes with `pip` right out of the box...

Read more on Python 3 for Mac [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html).

### Answer the question already

Now, all that said, you can simply use the following to install via pip:

```
sudo python3.5 -m pip install PyQt5
```

You'll likely have to use `sudo`. Output should look like:

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Downloading PyQt5-5.7-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (79.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 79.4MB 18kB/s 
Collecting sip (from PyQt5)
  Downloading sip-4.18.1-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 9.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: sip, PyQt5
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.7 sip-4.18.1
```

Don't forget to use the `-m` option. It allows for library modules to be run as scripts. From the `--help` entry:

```
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
```

**Note:** Older versions of PyQT **cannot** be installed via pip.